# retrieve a row (character name) after applying a calculus on a specific column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm a new R user (3.1.1).
I'd like to calculate the minimum value of a specific column in a dataframe and then to retrieve the index of that value which is a character type.
Here is an example of my data:

```
   Student.Name  Grade Id.number
1   John         80    123
2   Sarah        89    456
3   Bob          75    789
4   Matt         77    987
5   Ruth         81    765
```

In this case, I should apply a minimum function on the column "Grade" and the output should give me the name of the student. In this case, 75 is the minimum grade and therefore the output should print:

[1] "Bob"

could someone please help with that?

Comment: `with(df, Student_Name[which.min(Grade)])` (if `df` is your data set and `Student_Name` is the actual column name, as I assume you don't really have spaces in the column name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
with(mydata, Student.Name[which.min(Grade)])
```

Or if you have several values in `Grade` which all equal to the minimum value and you want to get them all (not only the first one), you could also do

```
with(mydata, Student_Name[Grade == min(Grade)])
```

(@DavidArenburg was suggesting this as I was typing it out myself.)

Notes:

- your column is probably called `Student.Name` (no spaces) unless you have done something clever/silly
- a more long-winded/basic way to do this would be

  ```
  mydata$Student.Name[which.min(mydata$Grade)]
  ```

  or

  ```
  mydata[which.min(mydata$Grade), "Student.Name"]
  ```

but `with()` is more compact/easier to read.

Comment: Thanks allot that worked! Yes the column names were Student.Name and Id.Number without space, as you called it right!

I have to mention that I find it strange that someone reduced my "reputation points". Was my question not legitimate? anyway, thanks again for the quick answer that was very helpful!

Comment: Someone may have thought your question "did not show research effort" or "was not useful" because it was too basic. I don't necessarily agree, but you may find that reading some introductory R material (there are many, many, many books, blog posts, online resources etc. available ...) will give you these sorts of answers.